# Do I need joist hangers on the ends of 12 ft. ceiling joists supported in the center?

Tags: basement, remodel

I am installing a non-load-bearing drop ceiling in a basement remodel. 2x4 joists fastened into ledger boards using #10 3-1/8 grk screws. There is a rat run in the middle of the 12 foot span with vertical supports (2x4s) attached to the existing joists. Do I need joist hangers?

Comment: How about a drawing indicating where these joist hangers would go.

Comment: You haven't said what they're carrying. Seems like it matters. @FreeMan, it's reasonable to assume that they'd be installed on the ledger. I'm not sure where else they _could_ go.

Comment: Is your drop ceiling going to be the usual 2x2 or 2x4 panels in a metal grid frame? Or something else?

Comment: If you have access through from the outside, then you could run the screws through the ledger boards into the ends of the new 2x4 joists. If you don't, then joist hangers with joist hanger nails/screws would be much easier. Some might toe-nail the new joists (since they're not really structural), but I'm not particularly good at that, so I wouldn't.

Comment: @FreeMan  It does seem like toe nailing splits wood more/easier.  For studs not matter much, but for hanging joists, it is more iffy.

Comment: Can the existing joists support the added weight of the structure your adding on? What size and type of floor joists are they? 2x material? TJIs?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, and you've toe-screwed the ends of the ceiling joists into the ledger (and done a good job at it), I see no reason for hangers with the 6ft. span.

This is especially true if you're hanging drywall and screw it into the ledger. The remaining load on the ceiling joists is quite small once you deduct what's supported by the ledger and the intermediate vertical supports.

If you're using self-drilling screws you shouldn't see much splitting in your lumber. If not, consider piloting just smaller than the screw shank.